manejar distintos layouts en una aplicación web sin mostrar parte del path en la URL? Next 14
Estoy desarrollando una web con next 14 y tengo dos layouts para todo el sitio. Por ejemplo, tengo un layout para la página de inicio de sesión que no incluye la barra de navegación y tiene un diseño diferente, y otro layout para el resto del sitio que sí incluye la barra de navegación y otras características.
Mi problema es que quiero que la URL no muestre la parte específica del path que indica qué layout se está utilizando. Por ejemplo, en lugar de tener miapp.com/login o miapp.com/home, preferiría tener simplemente miapp.com para ambas páginas.
Actualmente, mi solución consiste en tener un layout inicial que redirige a /login si el usuario no está autenticado, y a /home si lo está. Sin embargo, esto muestra la parte /home en la URL, lo cual quiero evitar si se navega mas dentro de la app como en alta o panel, no aparezca /home/panel sino /panel.


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Puede que implementando multiple root layouts puedas solucionar el problema.

Se puede usar Multiple Group Layouts

Se crean dos folders con la siguiente sintáxis:
(home)/
(login)/


Cada uno debe tener su propio archivo layout
(home)/
├─ layout.tsx
(login)/
├─ layout.tsx


Pero solo uno debe tener la pagina page, en este caso puede ser el grupo login:

mi solución consiste en tener un layout inicial

(home)/
├──layout.tsx
│ 
(login)/
├─ layout.tsx
├─ page.tsx


Ahora, despues de que el login fue exitoso, se redirecciona a algún segmento dentro del grupo home, en este caso el segmento panel:
(home)/
│  panel/
│  ├─ page.tsx
├──layout.tsx
│ 
(login)/
├─ layout.tsx
├─ page.tsx


El catch es que solo un grupo puede tener page, en este caso se uso para el login, de ahi entonces se debe empezar la navegación desde algun segmento en otro grupo, en ese segmento ya se puede tener un page, en este caso el segmento panel y este segmento tiene su propio rootlayout.
Nótese que cada grupo tiene su propio layout.
